# Spring: Modules/Components/Plugins

Tags: java, spring, plugins, module

I would like to know, if the java spring framework offers a module or plugin concept to develop modules/plugins for different spring applications (same code base). 
You know what I mean? I would like to develop one module/plugin, witch I can use in spring application 1 and spring application 2.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Spring framework itself (except spring core) is a huge collection of plugins. 
For example aop, jdbc, jms, orm, oxm - all these are plugins.
You can create spring component and package it into jar. Then you can use it as a part of other component. You can find services that are packaged in different jar and use it exactly as you can use service packaged into your current jar.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Do you have any specification of the necessary interfaces for such a module? I found this but it's rather poor on information: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.html#new-in-3-modules-build